# c# WPF вывод List<obj> и динамическое изменение

Tags: c#, wpf

Объект :

```
public class MyTestObject
{
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string first { get; set; }
        public string second { get; set; }
    }
}
```

У меня есть `List<MyTestObject.TestObject>`
Нужно вывести этот `List` объектов в две колонки по принципу

```
first1|second1
------|-------
first2|second2
------|-------
first3|second3
```

Как лучше это сделать? Длина листа меняется, точного значения нет.

Я примерно понимаю как можно это сделать костылём, но

Проблема в том, что мне нужно чтобы при изменении данных в этом `List` они тут же менялись в окне программы. Количество объектов в `List` при этом изменяться не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать паттерн [**MVVM**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern), то это делается так. Для сообщения таблице об изменениях в ячейках используется событие `PropertyChanged` из интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Строка таблицы будет выглядеть так:

**DataItem.cs**

```cs
public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _first;
    private string _second;
    public string First
    {
        get => _first; // то же самое, что { return _first; }
        set
        {
            _first = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(First));
        }
    }
    public string Second
    {
        get => _second;
        set
        {
            _second = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Second));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Далее, создаю `MainViewModel` класс, который будет выступать в роли датаконтекста для нашего окна. Это позволит нам легко и просто использовать биндинги.

`MainViewModel` так же реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`, чтобы `DataGrid` могла сама узнать, если я переключу `GridItems` на другую коллекцию.

`ObservableCollection` это практически то же самое, что и `List`, только внутри этой коллекции срабатывает событие `CollectionChanged`, с помощью него таблица узнает, были ли добавлены или удалены элементы из коллекции.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataItem> _gridItems;
    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> GridItems
    {
        get => _gridItems;
        set
        {
            _gridItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GridItems));
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // здесь можно добавить или загрузить элементы
        GridItems = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        GridItems.Add(new DataItem() { First = "first value", Second = "second value" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Теперь самое главное, как все это подружить с интерфейсом.

1. Добавить в `Window.DataContext` наш класс `MainViewModel`
2. Привязать `DataGrid` к коллекции `GridItems`
3. Привязать колонки таблицы к `First` и `Second`

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Column" Width="*" Binding="{Binding First}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second Column" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Second}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

И на последок:

- `INotifyPropertyChanged` находится в неймспейсе `System.ComponentModel`
- `ObservableCollection` - в `System.Collections.ObjectModel`

Дополнительная прелесть этого подхода к реализации еще в том, что данные внесенные в интерфейсе сразу же попадут в данные `GridItems` и их можно будет использовать в коде без непосредственного обращения к `DataGrid`.