# Работая со свойством TreeView.Items, которому присвоены коллекции типа ObservableCollection, как форсированно запустить процесс "CollectionChanged"?

Tags: c#, коллекции, avalonia

У меня есть компонент TreeView, и в него подтягиваются пункты из древовидной структуры через ObservableCollection. При добавлении новых пунктов сами-то пункты добавляются, но у этих пунктов есть глубинные свойства, и их изменение ни к чему ни приводит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я добавил 2 пункта с "латинским названием" newItem - это получилось, но добавление русского названия не достучалось до TreeView, с его точки зрения это верно: сами-то коллекции не поменялись. Что тут можно сделать? Напрашивающийся вариант: существует ли какой-то метод у ObservableCollection, который запускается при изменении коллекции, и который можно форсированно пульнуть, как типа коллекция поменялась? Тогда TreeView прочитает динамическое свойство (учитывающее русское название из глубинны) через Binding и всё встанет на свои места.

Схема кода примерно такова:

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class InfoItem : NotifyPropertyChanged, IEnumerable<InfoItem> // то, что поступает в пункты TreeView
{
    ...
    private readonly ObservableCollection<InfoValue> infoValues = new(); // Так называемые глубинные свойства
    private readonly ObservableCollection<InfoItem> items = new(); // Дочерние пункты
    ...

    public virtual string Declaration
    {
        get
        {
            InfoValue v = FindValueDeep("Имя");
            return v == null || v.Size <= 0 ? Caption : Caption + ". " + v.GetStrValue()[0];
            // Caption - свойство с одним геттером, вычисляется из name. Код длинный, поэтому не привожу

        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            if (!name.Equals(value))
            {
                string oldName = name;
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


}

public class InfoValue : IEnumerable
{
    ...
    private byte[] value; // Бинарное содержание этого глубинного свойства
    ...

    public string[] GetStrValue() // Через этот метод получаем русское название - для TreeView нужен только [0]-элемент
    {
        ...
        // Здесь происходит преобразование из бинарки в текстовый массив
        // Свойства могут быть не только текстовые, но они все хранятся в бинарках
    }
}
```

AXAML виджета:

```
<TreeView
    Name="SpaceItemTree"
    Items="{Binding SpaceTree}"
    Background="Aqua">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Declaration}"/>
        </TreeDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

ViewModel, привязываемая к виджету:

```
public class TreeWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public IReadOnlyList<InfoItem> SpaceTree => Program.classifier[2, 1, 1, 0, 5].Items; // Возвращает Items определённого пункта (класс InfoItem)
}
```

Comment: Нужна реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` на тех самых свойствах в классе, примеры где-то [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+INotifyPropertyChanged).

Comment: _но у этих пунктов есть глубинные свойства, и их изменение ни к чему ни приводит_ "...а класс с этими свойствами я не покажу, ну потому что зачем вам помогать отвечать на мой вопрос?"

Comment: @aepot я добавил в описание вопроса небольшую схему, код очень большой, дайте знать при необходимости, что ещё нужно показать

Comment: Окей, понятнее не стало, а что из того что вы показали, вы хотите видеть в интерфейсе? _их изменение ни к чему ни приводит_ - изменение чего, где оно?

Comment: @aepot, я хочу, чтобы когда в объекте InfoItem добавляется новое InfoValue в values или в конкретном InfoValue меняется содержание (value) - пункт в TreeView апдейтился так: `$"{item.caption}. {Item.GetValue(0).GetStrValue()[0]}"`. Кроме простого caption я всë указал в коде

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? А сейчас к чему у вас привязка данных? У вас на экране знаки вопроса, там наверное TextBlock, так? Он к чему-то привязан, так? К чему? Покажите разметку привязки, покажите это свойство в коде, на которое указывает эта привязка. У вас же проблема с обновлением, а не отображением, верно? Откройте в конце концов ссылку из вервого комментария, там все что вам нужно есть много раз.

Comment: @aepot попробовал вот эти 2 Ваших примера:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091809
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132061
Не получилось, апдейт не происходит. Дополнил код новой информацией, теперь-то я надеюсь достаточно инфы?

Comment: Вызвать OnProperryChanged с именем этого свойства в сеттерах всех его моставляющих. Наличие сеттера у самого свойства не требуется.

Comment: @aepot поставил в байндинг свойство Name, имеющее сеттер - сработало. Дело в том, что свойство Declaration - не имеет сеттера, оно вычисляемое, причём оно зависит не только от собственных свойств InfoItem, но и от вложенных элементов значения `List<InfoValues>` поля `infoValues`. Сейчас разбираюсь с тем, как `OnPropertyChange` перекинуть из списка в материнскую модель

Comment: Выглядит так, как-будто вы перемудрили. Вот еще пример нашел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1270508/373567. Упрощайте структуру данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вопрос свелся к тому, как отслеживать get-only свойство, которое состоит из других свойств, приведу простой абстрактный пример.

Пусть будет человек, у него есть имя и фамилия, а так же полное имя из имени и фамилии.

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class Person : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstName;
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get => _lastName;
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

Теперь при изменении имени или фамилии полное имя так же поменяется в интерфейсе.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
```