# Как прочитать данные из выбранной строки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю Task Manager, и при нажатии на 1 из строк в DataGrid я хочу вывести данные оттуда но я не знаю как это сделать.
Вот скриншот моего Task Manager

[image: TaskManagerImg]

Это кусок кода самого DataGrid

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid x:Name="ThreadList" SelectionChanged="ThreadList_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ProcessName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Process ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Threads" Binding="{Binding Threads.Count}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Запись всех данных в DataGrid происходит вот так

```
private void Tasks()
    {
        if(pr != null)
            pr.Clear();

        pr = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
        ProcessCount.Text = string.Empty;
        ThreadCount.Text = string.Empty;
        HandleCount.Text = string.Empty;

        threadsCount = 0;
        handleCount = 0;

        ThreadList.Items.Clear();

        ProcessCount.Text = Process.GetProcesses().Count().ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < pr.Count; i++)
        {
            ThreadList.Items.Add(pr[i]);
            threadsCount += pr[i].Threads.Count;
            handleCount += pr[i].HandleCount;
        }
        ThreadCount.Text = threadsCount.ToString();
        HandleCount.Text = handleCount.ToString();
    }
```

И вот как мне вывести данные строки на которую я нажал я не знаю

Comment: Уберите `x:Name="ThreadList"` и сделайте все на привязках. Сейчас вы вот прям совершенно все делаете не так. Вам не нужны имена, вам не нужны события, вам нужны лишь `Binding`. Не делайте лапшу в своем проекте в виде тесной связи UI с кодом, отвяжите их друг от друга, ведь это основа основ WPF, на котором он и базируется. Примерно [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553) у вас должно быть, внимание на то, что там в XAML нет ни единого `x:Name` и события!

Comment: А как я без имени ему передам данные то? Ну добавлю я биндинг, как я передам прямо в него таблицу?

Comment: Как как `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Вот самый простой пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1091821/373567 Вот еще куча примеров https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+%5Bwpf%5D+INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: А вот практически прямой ответ на ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135478/373567

Comment: В WPF если вы видите `x:Name`, и если это имя используется в C# коде не для стилей, не для UI, а как элемент работы с данными, то значит сразу что-то делается не так. Повторю, в WPF проекте должны быть максимально отделены данные от UI, у вас не должно быть в UI вообще чего либо, UI должен сам понимать что ему надо взять и когда. А у вас, как думаю вы видите (`ThreadList.Items.Add(pr[i]);`), все данные хранятся в UI. когда должны быть в виде простой коллекции/массива, лежащие в вашем классе, а уже потом привязываете в XAML `<DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}">`, с получением аналогично.